# Assign value to a variable in jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, drop-down-menu, variable-assignment

How do i assign a value to a variable in Jquery

```
    {var c2;
    $(c2).val("standard_desc");
    alert (c2);
    $('#ANDCriteria2').val(c2); 

    }
```

I am trying to set variable's value, it will be static. In next line i am trying to set dropdown's selected value using same variable. I know i can just type

```
$('#ANDCriteria2').val("standard_desc");
```

But i have different requirement, please guide.

Comment: You could just do `var c2 = "standard_desc";`

Comment: i did but it didnt work. i used alert box to return c2's value and it was undefined

Comment: didn't work how? crashed the browser? set the wrong value? kicked your dog? insulted your mother?

Comment: Checkout this doc on expressions. Look for `assignment operators` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Answer (score 3):

just declare the variable in JavaScript.

```
 <script>
   var c2;
   c2 = "value";
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

i have no idea why you have `{` there in your question.. are you missing something.. anyways assigning value to a variable is super simple.. use  `=` operator

```
var c2 = "standard_desc";
 alert(c2);
 $('#ANDCriteria2').val(c2);
```

Comment: thanks that helped , i dont know why but i was single quotes n it wasnt working for some bizzarre reason. But stuck in another problem now, i cannot set ANDCriteria2's value to c2. ANDCriteria2 is dropdown and i want standard_desc selected but it wont selected

Answer (score 2):

Try this way..

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<input id="points" type="text" value="">
<input id="var" type="text" value="">

$( "input" )
  .keyup(function() {
    var points= $("#points" ).val();
    $( "#var" ).val( (points));
  })
  .keyup();
```

Comment: Putting the variable in it's own parens solved my problem. Not sure why it needed it, but this put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

It is just JavaScript:

```
var c2 = "value";
```

Comment: Really wish there was more to this question, but yeah, well said.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function fun()
{
var c2="standard_desc";
    alert (c2);
    $('#ANDCriteria2').val(c2); 

    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is the solution:

```
var c2 = 'abs';
$('#myid').text(c2).val(c2);
```